# What is the advantage of using phoneGap API

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova

I am developing an application that will be running on different mobile OSs, so I would definetely  use phoneGap Build as a cross-mobile building tool. But my question is, why should I then use phonegap.js (the library) at all? Does its API includes features that I cannot reproduce with javascript libs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need sensors or actors (camera, microphone, etc.) from the device you don't need it. If you do, you should use it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In a nutshell, PhoneGap will give you acces to certain platform-specific features that wouldn't normally be available to a web app.

See [PhoneGap's feature list](http://phonegap.com/about/feature/) to see what you may gain. Note, though, that some (not all) of these features are also now supported by modern HTML5-compatible browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty sophisticated API.  You should definitely at least explore what it exposes.  Especially when it comes to anything involving the camera, it includes a lot of great methods.